Flutter - The named parameter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined
After upgrading Flutter version I am getting this error in background color

ThemeData(
...
...
...
 
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,

...
...
...);

FOR THE REMAINING PARTS
I was using
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,

-->
I converted to
 backgroundColor:
          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,

(Because I saw a solution on the internet, old one was giving a mistake)
How can I solve my problem? It seems that problem is about flutter version upgrading. What do you think? Any help will be appreciated.
flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.4.1  darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0-rc3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources


btw,  it should be another one duplicate or missing context

Can you include your current flutter version

I included thanks

Use   scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white instead of backgroundColor  if you need to change the color of scaffold. If you want to know more about the parameters of ThemeData you can Ctrl+click in windows or Cmd+click on mac on widget you want to know more.

thank you rational... I will try

I'm using scaffoldBackgroundColor, can I use for example canvasColor?

Use colorScheme.background instead.
This feature was deprecated after v3.3.0-0.5.pre.
example
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme(
          background: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
```


How? There is no guide about this on the Internet

my flutter version is 3.19.5, so i can see this information, it haven't been deleted yet@gurkanstack

there is no colorScheme.background attribute

@gurkanstack i just updated my answer, take a look

I tried it but it needs other properties and I don't know how to fill

onprimary, onsecondary, etc. what are these? why does flutter team make things harder? what are their purposes? I'm tired of making tons of changes every flutter upgrade. Are they kidding us?

@gurkanstack sorry, that's what i found, i'm confused too, perhaps use scaffoldBackgroundColor is a better way? or you can use ColorScheme.light
